# order post in nodejs + mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am ordering the posts by age of the user and not by date of the post,
I am using nodejs and mongodb:

```
 router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session._id && req.session.user) {
    user.getAll((err, users) => {
      var posts = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < users[i].posts.length; j++) {
          users[i].posts[j].timeago = ta.ago(users[i].posts[j].createdAt);
          posts.push({ user: users[i], post: users[i].posts[j] });
        }
      }

      user.findOne({ username: req.session.user }, (error, req_user) => {
        /*   for(var z=0;z<req_user.followers.length;z++) {
            user.findOne({_id:req_user.followers[z]}, (e,followedUser) => {
              posts.push(followedUser.posts)
            })
          }
          */
        var lastSeen = ta.ago(req_user.lastLogin);
        //console.log(posts)
        res.render("home", {
          user: req_user,
          title: req.app.conf.name,
          lastSeen: lastSeen,
          people: users,
          posts: posts.reverse()
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.render("auth/login", {
      title: req.app.conf.name,
      error: false
    });
  }
});
```

I would like to order it by the most recent post, any solution?

I think the main part of the problem is:

```
posts.push({ user: users[i], post: users[i].posts[j] });
```

and that you should use .sort (createdAt), but I don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

You should sort the posts before adding them to the array, something like the following:

```
function sort_array_of_obj(a, b) {
  if (a.createdAt < b.createdAt){
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.createdAt > b.createdAt){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {        
    users[i].posts.sort(sort_array_of_obj)

    for (var j = 0; j < users[i].posts.length; j++) {
      users[i].posts[j].timeago = ta.ago(users[i].posts[j].createdAt);      
    }
    posts.push({ user: users[i], post: users[i].posts[j] });
}
```

Comment: thank Ivan!, but keep ordering by blocks:
name 1:
  post1 
  post2
  post3
  post4
name2
  post1
  post2

name3 ...

Comment: My mongodb model: (Colletion users)

Comment: {
    post: {
      _id: '',
      author: '',
      authorID: '',
      static_url: null,
      caption: '',
      category: '',
      comments: [],
      likes: [],
      type: null,
      createdAt: 2020-07-02T09:33:58.087Z,
      lastEditedAt: 2020-07-02T09:33:58.087Z,
      timeago: '3 weeks ago'
    }
  },

Comment: Yeah, i made a mistake as well, you should move the line ```posts.push({ user: users[i], post: users[i].posts[j] });``` outside of the for loop.